# WatiN click on element not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, watin

Hello i trying to make click on element 'a'  with WatiN(dll) and i can't get to this element to make click.Privous clicks works fine, but this one is not working
 here my code

```
var browser = new IE("https://www.tesst.com");
browser2.TableRow(Find.ById("kyos_filaCuenta_00")).FireEvent("onmouseover");
browser2.Link(Find.ById("kyos_enlaceIrAMovsCuenta_EUR0")).Click();

/*i tried this one too

TableCell tb = browser2.TableCell(Find.ByClass("kyos_positionFirstElementTd ancho200   columna0"));
Link link = tb.Link(lnk => lnk.GetAttributeValue("onclick").ToLower().Contains(".close(true)"));
link.Click();
*/
```

Here Html page

```
<tbody>
<tr id="kyos_filaCuenta_00" class="cuentaNoFavorita">
<td class="ancho20 kyos_anchoCheckTd">
<td class="kyos_positionFirstElementTd ancho200 columna0">
<a id="kyos_enlaceIrAMovsCuenta_EUR0" class="cursorPointer numCuenta" onclick="kyos_irAMovsCuenta('ES9601824649840201502683','','EUR','','BANCO BILBAO VIZCAYA ARGENTARIA S.A','20199802','false','','VISONIC IBERICA DE SEGURIDAD S.L.');return false;">ES9601824649840201502683</a>
</td>
<td class=" columna1">
</tbody>
```

Comment: What browser do you use? Do you get any JS errors?

Comment: IE not there is no error in clien/browser it says the id not exist  Could not find A element tag matching criteria: Attribute 'id' equals 'kyos_enlaceIrAMovsCuenta_EUR0'

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
        var _driver = new ChromeDriver();// or new IE()
        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.tesst.com");
        _driver.FindElement(By.Id(element)).Click();
        //do what you need
        _driver.Quit();
```

More proper way to do this is to set up unit tests, something like (Use resharper plugin to run tests):

```
[TestFixture]
class LoginTest
{        
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void FixtureSetup()
    {
        _driver = new ChromeDriver();
        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.tesst.com");
    }
    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void FixtureTearDown()
    {
        _driver.Quit();
    }

    [TestCase("kyos_enlaceIrAMovsCuenta_EUR0")]
    public void PaywallClosedArticleCommertialTest(string element)
    {
        _driver.FindElement(By.Id(element)).Click();
        //add assert
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try finding the element i.e., link in the T2 element which is parent

```
browser2.TableRow(Find.ById("kyos_filaCuenta_00")).Link(Find.ById("kyos_enlaceIrAMovsCuenta_EUR0")).Click();
```